# New to Go, trying to sort out how to process JSON

Tags: json, go

Coming from languages like Python, Ruby, and JS, I am really struggling with Go right now.  It feels overly complex, but I am hoping I am just missing something.

Right now I have code that can successfully call Boston's MBTA API (**using their public developer key)** and return all route information.

I have dropped the code here: http://pastebin.com/PkBaP714 and here: http://pastebin.com/7mRxgrpp

Sample data returned: http://pastebin.com/M2hzMKYs

I want to return two things 1) JUST each route_type and mode_name, and 2) when route_type is called each of the route_id and route_name.

For whatever reason I am just totally lost.  I've spent 16 hours staring at documentation and I feel like I am looking at a foreign language :).

It may be too much to ask for specific help, but I would LOVE IT.

Comment: Just as a note, the API key in the code is public.

Comment: The go json package is well documented, and has been written about at length on many blogs (including the official golang.org). Can you give us some idea about what you've tried and hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map them to a new type:

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    c := gombta.Client{APIKey: apikey, URL: apiurl}

    // get a list of routes by type
    d, err := c.GetRoutes(format)
    check(err)

    var toPrint interface{}

    if typeid == 9999 {
        type Result struct {
            RouteType string `json:"route_type"`
            ModeName  string `json:"mode_name"`
        }
        rs := []Result{}
        for _, m := range d.Mode {
            rs = append(rs, Result{
                RouteType: m.RouteType,
                ModeName:  m.ModeName,
            })
        }
        toPrint = rs
    } else {
        type Result struct {
            RouteID   string `json:"route_id"`
            RouteName string `json:"route_name"`
        }
        rs := []Result{}
        for _, m := range d.Mode {
            if fmt.Sprint(typeid) == m.RouteType {
                for _, r := range m.Route {
                    rs = append(rs, Result{
                        RouteID:   r.RouteID,
                        RouteName: r.RouteName,
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        toPrint = rs
    }

    j, err := json.MarshalIndent(toPrint, "", " ")
    fmt.Printf("RouteTypes: ")
    os.Stdout.Write(j)
}
```

Comment: Dude, thank you -- I know it's obnoxious, but you don't understand how much you just helped Go make sense to me.